# wxPython - How to implement a colour slider

Tags: slider, wxpython, python-3.6

for my project I want to implement a colour slider such as the one in the ColourCubeDialog or in Windows' native colour picker dialog. Here are some pictures to illustrate what I mean:

https://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFColourSlider/WpfColourSlider1.jpg
https://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/XColorSpectrumCtrl/XColorSpectrumCtrl4.png

I found the `wx.lib.colourchooser.pycolourslider.PyColourSlider` while digging around in the wx package and I thought I could use that to implement the colour slider. I tried it the following way, but it only shows a white square (approx. 15 pixels) surrounded by a thin black border in the upper left hand corner.

```
import wx
from wx.lib.colourchooser.pycolourslider import PyColourSlider

app = wx.App()

frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, title="PyColourSlider",style=wx.MINIMIZE_BOX|
                 wx.SYSTEM_MENU|wx.CAPTION|wx.CLOSE_BOX|wx.RESIZE_BORDER)
panel = wx.Panel(frame)
slider = PyColourSlider(panel, -1)
slider.SetBaseColour(wx.Colour(80, 100, 120)) # some random color
slider.DrawBuffer()

frame.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

What am I doing wrong? Is the `PyColouSlider` the right way to go or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

I found something that is not the ultimate answer to my own question, but it helped me.
The `from wx.lib.colourchooser.` folder contains lots of parts that, when put together, allow the user to create an entire colour picker. There is even an implementation of a complete colour picker that can be embedded in a window/frame/whatever. It's called `pycolourchooser`.